# Javascript to get the div info

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 4 `<div>` tag and `<a>` tag for each `<div>` tags.
In each and every `div` tag i have inserted 2 `span` tag and a `a` tag.

When the `a` tag is clicked i need to get the product name and the price of that `div`

Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/8VCWU/

I get the below warning message when i use the codes in the answer ...
[image: warning message]

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question anywhere, so what should we answer?

Comment: You should be careful with duplicating ids - might cause you issues retrieve the correct elements in future.

Comment: here is my product code http://jsfiddle.net/MeUfZ/

Comment: @user1565383: See my answer given below

Comment: is that working with my code http://jsfiddle.net/MeUfZ/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".get").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $parent = $(this).closest(".item");
    var itemName = $(".postname", $parent).text();
    var itemPrice = $(".price", $parent).text();

    alert(itemName + " / " + itemPrice);    
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8VCWU/1/)

Note that you had a lot of repeated `id` attributes which is invalid code and will cause you problems. I've converted the `#item` elements and their children to use classes instead.

Comment: Quick note. I'd make a point of pushing jQuery's [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method for event binding as that's their recommended practice.

Comment: `click()` uses `on()` under the hood anyway.

Comment: Yeah but you lose event delegation and namespacing that way.

Comment: Your links don't have the `get` class on them, and have an inline `onclick` handler too.

Answer (score 1):

### jQuery

```
$(".get").click(function(event){    

    event.preventDefault(); /*To Prevent the anchors to take the browser to a new URL */

    var item = $(this).parent().find('#postname').text();
    var price = $(this).parent().find('#price').text(); 
    var result = item + " " + price;    
    alert(result)
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/wuR5M/)

**A Quick Note about [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/id):**

> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).
>
> A unique identifier so that you can identify the element with. You can use this as a parameter to getElementById() and other DOM functions and to reference the element in style sheets.

Answer (score 1):

solution is  below

use the blow code and try it

```
<a data-role="link" href="javascript:linkHandler('<%= obj.productname %>', '<%= obj.price %>')" class="get" >Add <a>



function linkHandler(name, price)
{
    alert(name);
    alert(price);
    var name = name;
    var price = price;
    var cartItem = new item(name, parseFloat(price));
            // check duplicate
            var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(viewModel.cartItems(), function(item){ return item.name == name; });
            if(match){
                match.qty(match.qty() + 1);
            } else {
              viewModel.cartItems.push(cartItem);
var rowCount = document.getElementById("cartcontent1").getElementsByTagName("TR").length;
document.getElementById("Totala").innerHTML = rowCount;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery

```
​$('a.get').on('click',function(){
 var parent = $(this).parent(); 
 var name = $(parent+' #postname').text(); 
 var price = $(parent+' #price').text();    
});​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

Or again:

```
$('a').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var $price = $(this).siblings('#price').text();
    var $postname = $(this).siblings('#postname').text();
    alert($price);
    alert($postname);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function getPrice(currentClickObject)
{
   var priceSpan = $(currentClickObject).parent("div:first").children("#price");
   alert($(priceSpan).html());
}
```

and add to your a tag:

```
<a href="..." onClick="getPrice(this)">...</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use classed instead of id if you have more than one in your code.
The function you're looking for is siblings() http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Here's your updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8VCWU/14/

Comment: Have you selected the latest jQuery from the framework list on the left?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I cleaned up the HTML as mentioned using the same Id more than once is a problem.

Using jQuery and the markup I provided the solution is trivial.

Make a note of the CSS on the below fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8VCWU/27/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#itmLst a.get").click(function(){
        var $lstItm = $(this).parents("li:first");
        var pName = $lstItm.find("span.postname").html();
        var price = $lstItm.find("span.price").html();

        alert("Product Name: " + pName + " ; Price: " + price);
    });
});
```

Comment: If possible can you check with my code and tell me its working or  not working http://jsfiddle.net/MeUfZ

Comment: You keep changing the framework in jsfiddle to mootools if you want to use jQuery change the framework to that also you have errors in your html markup dangling </div> tags ect...

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in your html tags and replace all repeated Ids with class, because you have repeated many ids in your html and it causes trouble so it is wrong structure. In HTML, you have to give unique id to each and every tag. it will not be conflicted with any other tag.

Here i have done complete bins demo. i have also specified all alternative ways to find tag content using proper jQuery selector. the demo link is as below:

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp8v

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $("a.get").click(function() {

        var itemName = $(this).parent().find(".postname").text().trim();
        var itemPrice = $(this).parent().find(".price").text().trim();

        //OR another Alternate
        // var itemName=$(this).parents(".item").find(".postname").text().trim();
        // var itemPrice=$(this).parents(".item").find(".price").text().trim();

        //OR another Alternate

        //var itemName=$(this).closest(".item").find(".postname").text().trim();
        //  var itemPrice=$(this).closest(".item").find(".price").text().trim();

        //OR another Alternate

        //var itemName=$(this).siblings(".postname").text().trim();
        //var itemPrice=$(this).siblings(".price").text().trim();
        alert(itemName + " / " + itemPrice);

    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp8v

You can check above all alternatives by un-commenting one by one. all are working fine.